# DevExpress ExportToText / ExportToCSV fail to produce stream

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, export-to-csv, xtragrid

I am trying to basically export a Grid contents to a CSV file.  The datasource checks out fine as I pass the exact same SQL to a physical grid and its fine.  But when I try to create the Grid and View dynamically - and Export the contents - the Stream is never populated.  (Length = 0)

```
Dim opts As New DevExpress.XtraPrinting.TextExportOptions
Dim grdGrid As New XtraGrid.GridControl
Dim gdvGrid As New XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView(grdGrid)

grdGrid.Name = "Grid1"
grdGrid.DataSource = dtsDataset.Tables(0)
grdGrid.MainView = gdvGrid

gdvGrid.Name = "GridView1"
gdvGrid.OptionsView.ColumnAutoWidth = False
gdvGrid.BestFitColumns()
gdvGrid.OptionsPrint.PrintFooter = False

gdvGrid.OptionsPrint.PrintDetails = True
gdvGrid.OptionsPrint.ExpandAllDetails = True
gdvGrid.RefreshData()

opts.QuoteStringsWithSeparators = True
opts.TextExportMode = XtraPrinting.TextExportMode.Text

Dim tryStream As New IO.MemoryStream

gdvGrid.ExportToText(tryStream, opts)

gdvGrid.ExportToCsv(tryStream)
```

I have added alot of trial and error above, which is probably not ideal.  Nonetheless I cannot get the Stream (any stream) to fill with data and no error is produced.  Both streams (I added one for testing) have an empty buffer.

The problem seems to be with the GridView - when I examine the Columns property the Count = 0 ... I may need a hand setting up dynamic GridViews properly (and then the Export will probably work fine)

I use

```
Imports DevExpress
Imports DevExpress.XtraPrinting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this working, you need the extra line for BindingContext as below:
(ForceInitialize is not essential in this context, but in other contexts - within Form Load for example - it is very helpful - so I left it intact)

```
Dim grdGrid As New XtraGrid.GridControl 
Dim gdvGrid As New XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView(grdGrid)


grdGrid.Name = "Grid1"
grdGrid.DataSource = dtsDataset.Tables(0)
grdGrid.MainView = gdvGrid

' These TWO lines below are ESSENTIAL to 
' actually get the GridView to fill with the Data
' if the Grid and View is not created on a physical form
grdGrid.BindingContext = New BindingContext
grdGrid.ForceInitialize()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the GridControl in a wrong way. It is a visual component, and it is not intended to work as a background service to produce reports. [XtraReports](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument2162) library is better suits your requirements.

If you prefer your way, try adding the GridControl to a visible Form or UserControl. You can make the GridControl invisible or hide it under other visual component. The only thing for what you need to add the GridControl to the Form is to initialize its with the BindingContext instance.

Comment: Thanks @Uranus - you have partly answered the question so you get the points.  However, I do want to print the exact contents (and perhaps the formatting) of the GridView.  Is there a preferred method?  PrintingSystem perhaps?  I will use XtraReports for the full features available in the Reports, but in this instance we need only and exactly the grid contents.